# OAuth C# Library for Google, Yahoo! Twitter

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth

I'm looking for a library that will allow me to use OAuth in my ASP.NET/C# applications, such that I can authenticate users using one of the following OAuth providers

1. Google
2. Yahoo!
3. Twitter

I've looked at various open source libraries and find that there is one issue or another with them (some don't work at all, some work against one service not not others). I've also looked at OAuthDotNet and I must admit that I find it way too complicated to figure out how to begin using it and so I've not really tried it.

So essentially I'm looking for a simple to use library that works against the above mentioned providers (at least).

Comment: Just a note, OAuth is not for authentication, it's for authorization. A subtle but important difference. OAuth doesn't tell you if it's the person you want, only if they are allowed to submit/post/access the relevant site.

Comment: See a list of libraries for oAuth 2.0 available: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997172/oauth-2-0-service-provider-net-libraries

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Jackie I have a blog post on this
[OAuth C# Library](http://www.matlus.com/oauth-c-library/)

There is a library (including source code) and a simple sample project you can download to get started with this.

I've tested it against
1. Google
2. Twitter
3. Yahoo
4. Vimeo

You don't mention the version of OAuth you'd like to support so you should know that the library supports OAuth 1.0 revision A only and not OAuth 2.0. Most site today support OAuth 1.0 revision a.

I've kept the sample project very simple intentionally, so those starting out down this path don't have to struggle trying to figure out how to use the library. The library is not "over engineered" like I believe some libraries out there are so it is fairly simple to enhance if need be. But I suggest you attempt that only after you've familiarized yourself with the OAuth protocol.

The project in fact is an open source project hosted on Google code (link in the blog post).

Note: Due to the way Yahoo! has implemented their service it is not possible (or not simple) to test against their service from your development machine.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Wow! blog post is excellent and the library and sample app you've provided just works!. I took at look at the sample project and in less than 2 minutes I can see exactly what is going on and what I need to do in my application in order to use OAuth with your library. After spending days trying to get something to work and something simple to figure out I've finally found exactly what I've been looking for. Great stuff and Thank you!

Comment: Hi Shiv, thanks for the nice codes. I am trying to use it , but gives errorors     parameter_absent
oauth_parameters_absent:oauth_consumer_key&oauth_signature_method&oauth_signature&oauth_timestamp&oauth_nonce            when MakeRequest is called, can you help me to make it working.

Comment: Note that the URL above didn't work for me. Seems to have changed to this... http://www.matlus.com/oauth-c-library/

Comment: @ShivKumar Images on that URL are broken - fancy fixing them?

Answer (score 3):

[DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/) is open source library that supports OpenID, OAuth and
support for your site visitors to login with their OpenIDs.

[Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries) Libraries in different languages.

[Google Data client libraries](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/client-libraries.html) are written to support client applications to access APIs.
Libraries are written in different types of languages.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to just to Twitter then I would suggest [twitterizer](http://www.twitterizer.net/). It's a great library with a fairly good community and support.

Comment: I did say I needed at least the 3 I've mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

http://byatool.com/c/connect-your-web-app-to-twitter-using-hammock-csharp/ (Wayback archive [link](http://web.archive.org/web/20160424013642/http://byatool.com/c/connect-your-web-app-to-twitter-using-hammock-csharp).)

http://hammock.codeplex.com/  ([Moved to github](http://web.archive.org/web/20110609091513/http://hammock.codeplex.com/) here: https://github.com/danielcrenna/vault/tree/master/hammock)

these link might be helpful.

Comment: This library does too much other stuff that I'm not interested.