# How to login with gmail for my web site

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

my Website having login with facebook account, i want develop the login with gmail.And get the user's data save into my database. If u know any information about login with gmail,Share the information for me.

Comment: Why did you tag this with both C# and VB.NET? Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 1):

How about using OAuth? [Google has great articles](https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/oauth) on how you do that. There's also [another question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380473/oauth-c-sharp-library-for-google-yahoo-twitter) regarding OAuth libraries for Google, Twitter and Yahoo.

[Here is a tutorial on "How to Integrate Google Authentication in Asp.Net Application"](http://srinivasganaparthi.blogspot.se/2011/04/how-to-integrate-google-authentication.html).